# How to find median and set it as rank from students scores and index

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i have this set of student score in descending order with their respective index/serial number(auto generated from class size).

What i want to achieve it this in the student ranks

| Index(Serial No) | scores | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 95.0 | 2.0 |
| 2. | 95.0 | 2.0 |
| 3. | 95.0 | 2.0 |
| 4. | 90.0 | 4.5 |
| 5. | 90.0 | 4.5 |
| 6. | 85.0 | 6.0 |
| 7. | 70.0 | 9.0 |
| 8. | 70.0 | 9.0 |
| 9. | 70.0 | 9.0 |
| 10. | 70.0 | 9.0 |
| 11. | 70.0 | 9.0 |
| 12. | 65.0 | 12.5 |
| 13. | 65.0 | 12.5 |
| 14. | 65.0 | 12.5 |
| 15. | 65.0 | 12.5 |
| 16. | 60.0 | 16.0 |
| 17. | 40.0 | 17.0 |

For students with index no. 1, 2 and 3  they are rank 2  that means there is no number one in the class. And rank ( for our case is 2) is found by find the middle value ( median) of these three numbers.

Index 6 is still rank 6 in the class which is ok.
and there is no rank 5 in the class which is also ok.

Index 4 and 5 have total count of 2 which is even number, and  have equal scores therefore we find median index which
(4+5)÷2= 4.5

Index 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11 which total count of 5 which is odd number  have equal scores so the rank is found by find the median number which is 9.
(7+8+9+10+11)/5=9

So what I want to achieve is  to calculate median and give same rank for the students whose scores are equal and their count is even number. For example below codes results was supposed to be 8.5 and not 8.0 because for these indexes median is (6.0+7.0+8.0+9.0+10.0+11.0)/6=8.5 also  for index 12.0 and 13.0 median was supposed to be 12.5 and not 12.0 since (12.0+13.0)/2= 12.5.
Note: for the case of index 1.0 to 5.0 it works fine.

Here is my codes that give the below results:-

```
 public class ViewStudentScores extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private StudentAdapter studentAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_student_scores);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Student student = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                students.add(student);
            }

            // Sort students by score in descending order
            Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
                    return Double.compare(student2.getScore(), student1.getScore());
                }
            });

            // Assign ranks considering median of index numbers for students with the same score
            int totalStudents = students.size();
            int startIndex = 0;
            while (startIndex < totalStudents) {
                int endIndex = startIndex + 1;
                while (endIndex < totalStudents && students.get(startIndex).getScore() == students.get(endIndex).getScore()) {
                    endIndex++;
                }
                double medianIndex = (startIndex + endIndex - 1) / 2;
                double rank = medianIndex + 1;

                // Assign rank to students with the same score
                for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
                    students.get(i).setRank(rank);
                }

                startIndex = endIndex;
            }

            // Update RecyclerView with the sorted and ranked students
            studentAdapter.setStudents(students);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Handle database error
        }
    });
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the line where you calculate the median

```
double medianIndex = (startIndex + endIndex - 1) / 2;
```

you are doing integer division as both sides are integers, since `startIndex` and `endIndex` are ints. Either cast one of them or both to double or make the divisor `2` a double. The easiest way to fix could be:

```
double medianIndex = (startIndex + endIndex - 1) / 2.0;
```